# Multiple diff Tools

Tags: git, configuration

I had set up my *git* to use P4Merge as the diff tool, as described [here](http://progit.org/book/ch7-1.html). So, `git diff` will trigger the P4Merge.

However, sometimes I find working with the UNIX `diff` is faster and more efficient (because no GUI involved). How do I set up git so that I can easily choose which diff tool I would like to trigger? Is this possible? For example:

```
$ git diff     # to trigger P4Merge
$ git difftool # to trigger UNIX diff
```

My `git config --list`:

```
code.editor=vi
merge.tool=p4merge
mergetool.extMerge.cmd=extMerge $BASE $LOCAL $REMOTE $MERGED
mergetool.extMerge.trustexitcode=false
diff.external=extDiff
mergetool.prompt=false
mergetool.keepbackup=false
mergetool.p4merge.path=/usr/local/bin/p4merge
```

Comment: The URL *here* mentioned above is broken, can you please update?

Answer (score 10):

You can just explicitly indicate which difftool you want to use. I have this in my `~/.gitconfig`:

```
[diff]
    tool = vimdiff

[difftool "winmerge"]
    name = WinMerge
    trustExitCode = true
    cmd = "/c/Users/rkasten/Google\\ Drive/Apps/WinMerge/WinMergeU.exe" -u -e $LOCAL $REMOTE
```

And then I have the following aliases setup:

```
alias gdt='git difftool'
alias gdtw='git difftool --tool=winmerge'
```

Using masukomi's example, you could just add the following to your gitconfig:

```
[difftool "Kaleidoscope"]
    cmd = ksdiff --whatevs
```

And use `alias gdtk='git difftool --tool=Kaleidoscope'` to use Kaleidoscope.

All this works in git 2.7.

Answer (score 5):

**UPDATE:**
If like OP you want to make `git difftool` invoke the default diff functionality instead of an external tool then simple version at the end of this answer works. However the method I prefer and recommend if you just want multiple diff tools is the .gitconfig file method as described in [DrStrangeprok's answer.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34954253/315605)

---

You can set the following bash script as your external editing tool. 
(ie: replace the contents of extDiff with it) 
It is not quite as simple as git diif1 / git diff2 but it works.
EDIT: see bottom for a simpler version

```
#!/bin/bash

# Parameters from git:
# 1    2        3       4        5        6       7
# path old-file old-hex old-mode new-file new-hex new-mode

CONTINUE=1
while [ $CONTINUE == 1 ]
do

    # Present Options
    echo "1. P4Merge"
    echo "2. Unix diff"
    echo "3. Cancel"
    echo -n "Choose diff tool[1]: "

    # Read in user choice
    read -n 1 OPTION

    # move down a line
    echo ""

    # if user didn't enter a choice default to 1
    if [[ $OPTION == "" ]] ; then
        OPTION="1"
    fi

    # Launch diff tool based on OPTION
    case $OPTION in
        1) /Applications/p4merge.app/Contents/MacOS/p4merge "$2" "$5" ; CONTINUE=0 ;;
        2) diff "$2" "$5" ; CONTINUE=0 ;;
        3) exit ;;
        *) echo "\"$OPTION\" is not valid " ;;
    esac


    # This sleep has two purposes
    # 1) on an invalid choice it delays the menu just a hair
    # 2) keeps this script alive long enough that git will not just move onto the next file
    #    instantly if diffing multiple files.
    sleep 1

done
```

Simple Version without a menu
add this function to your .bashrc
if you use 'git difftool' then it will use the default diff

```
function git {

    if [[ $1 == "difftool" ]] ; then
        git config --global --unset diff.external
        command git diff
        git config --global diff.external extDiff
    else
        command git "$@"
    fi

}
```

Comment: Anything simpler than this? :)

Comment: Yes actually, I just thought of another way much more like what you wanted, I edited my answer above

Comment: @Appak you probably need to make it `command git "$@"` instead because otherwise `git commit -am "all done"` won't work

Answer (score 5):

Git can easily manage a visual and command line diff. No fancy tweaking is required

git diff (by default) uses unix `diff`

if you want to use a visual diffing tool as well the correct way to set it up is in your `~/.gitconfig` file with a section like this:

```
[difftool "Kaleidoscope"]
    cmd = ksdiff --partial-changeset --relative-path \"$MERGED\" -- \"$LOCAL\" \"$REMOTE\"
```

What comes after the `cmd =` is specific to your particular visual diffing application.

It is *not* standard practice to manipulate `git diff` to send content to a visual diffing app. As such, the question seeks an answer that is 100% backwards from the built in functionality.

See the [git-difftool man page](http://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-difftool.html) for more details.

Answer (score 1):

It'd be nice if Git can somehow have different settings for each, but if not, to expand on Appak's answer, the following added to `.bashrc` can invoke text diff, opendiff (FileMerge), or P4Merge diff:

```
function git {
    if [ $1 == "tdiff" ]
    then
        git config --global --unset diff.external
        command git diff
    elif [ $1 == "diff" ]
    then
        git config --global diff.external ~/bin/git-diff-opendiff
        command git diff
    elif [ $1 == "pdiff" ]
    then
        git config --global diff.external ~/bin/git-diff-p4diff
        command git diff
    else
        command git "$@"
    fi
}
```

and just make sure you have the proper `git-diff-opendiff` and `git-diff-p4diff` already set up (they are the shell scripts).

Answer (score 0):

You write

> However, sometimes I find working with the UNIX diff is faster and
>   more efficient (because no GUI involved). How do I set up git so that I can easily choose which diff tool I would like to trigger?

So the answer to this question should simply take advantage of git's ability to differentiate between console- and gui-based diff tools and not rely on writing an external command.

By providing the `-g` option to `git difftool`, the diff tool to use will be read from the configured variable `diff.guitool` instead of `diff.tool`.

```
[alias]
    d = difftool -g
    dc = difftool
[diff]
    guitool = p4merge
    tool = diff
```

That's it. You would invoke your gui tool `p4merge` using `git d <file1> <file2>` or similar and your console tool using `git dc <file1> <file2>`.