# Separate GIT Diff and Merge Tools for CMD and VS

Tags: git, visual-studio

I used this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/44549734/1584626 to create a GIT config file, which will use Visual Studio Code as diff and merge tool.

This is fine as long as I work from CMD, but when I'm already in Visual Studio (mind the lack of *Code* here), I'd like to use the integrated diff and merge tools - is there some way to accomplish this?